# populating Listview with arrayadapter<HashMap<String, String>>

Tags: android, android-intent

I am using following code but it does not populates the listview.

```
  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>> (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , menuItems));
```

The problem is the above code creates adapter successfully but it does not show in listview.

Thank you

Comment: arrayadapter couldnt work with hashmap array list have to be string try to create simple type arraylist hashmap.getvalues

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15816590/hashmap-working-in-simpleadapter-but-not-working-in-custom-array-adapter
Refer this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement SimpleAdapter for filling data from ArrayList of HashMap as:

```
SimpleAdapter listadapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems, R.layout.row,

new String[] {"textone", "texttwo", "txtthree"}, new int[] 

{R.id.textone, R.id.texttwo, R.id.texttwo});
```

but for implementing [SimpleAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html) you must create a layout for row with Views you want in single row

for more help you can see following tutorials to fill ListView with ArrayList of hashMap:

http://shenhengbin.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/listview-simpleadapter/

http://shenhengbin.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/listview-simpleadapter/

Comment: This adapter works for custom list while I am using the listview control

Comment: @user1214458 : i'm not clear what u want to say. ListView control is always same but it's delend on you either use custom Adapter or or Default Adapter getView method to create listview row

Comment: I above i am confused in new int[] 

{R.id.textone, R.id.texttwo, R.id.texttwo}); for listview we do not have these  ..

Comment: These three are id of View to which you want to map HaspMap Values.like suppose you have Three item in one HaspMap instance and your ArrayList content 5 instances of this HashMap.you want to show these three items in one row of listView.then what you will need Create an layout for listview row with Three textView or any other Views like button ,imageView's etc. and pass these controls id to SimpleAdapter   `new int[] {R.id.textone, R.id.texttwo, R.id.texttwo}`) as last parameter and row layout id ` R.layout.row` as third parameter

Comment: and i also share an tutorial link in my answer in which author is doing same as you want

Comment: Yes but I am using simple listview which is available in eclipes panel. So i want to know about that

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20469/discussion-between-imran-khan-and-user1214458)