# hashmap working in simpleadapter but not working in custom array adapter

Tags: android, listview, hashmap, lazy-loading, android-arrayadapter

Hashmap for the code below is working for simpleadapter array but not for custom array adapter .Why ? and how do I fix it ? Please Help.Unable to resolve .Tried everything.

I am using lazyLoading class to load images.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {


                HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) list.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Toast.makeText(CustomizedListView.this, "ID '" + o.get("KEY_TITLE") + "' was clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

            }
```

The entire code which is crashing at onclick shown above :

```
public class CustomizedListView extends Activity {
    // All static variables
    static final String URL = "https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topalbums/limit=20/json";
    // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_SONG = "song"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    static final String KEY_ARTIST = "artist";
    static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";
    static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";

    ListView list;
    LazyAdapter adapter;

    HashMap<String, String> map;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(URL);


        try {
            JSONObject arr2 = json.getJSONObject("feed");
            JSONArray arr = arr2.getJSONArray("entry");

            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject e1 = arr.getJSONObject(i);

                JSONArray arr3 = e1.getJSONArray("im:image");

                JSONObject arr8 = e1.getJSONObject("im:name");

                JSONObject arr10 = e1.getJSONObject("im:artist");

                    JSONObject e12 = arr3.getJSONObject(0);

            // creating new HashMap
             map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL,  e12.getString("label"));

            map.put(KEY_ARTIST, arr8.getString("label"));
            map.put(KEY_TITLE, arr10.getString("label"));
            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            songsList.add(map);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "Network communication error!", 5).show();
        }


        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
        adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);        
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Click event for single list row
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                                HashMap<String, String> o= (HashMap<String, String>) list.getItemAtPosition(position);                  

                                Toast.makeText(CustomizedListView.this, "ID '" + o.get("title") + "' was clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 



            }
        });     
    }   
}
```

This Code below works perfectly:

```
public class Main extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


        JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://api.geonames.org/earthquakesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&username=demo");

        try{

            JSONArray  earthquakes = json.getJSONArray("earthquakes");

            for(int i=0;i<earthquakes.length();i++){                        
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    
                JSONObject e = earthquakes.getJSONObject(i);

                map.put("id",  String.valueOf(i));
                map.put("name", "Earthquake name:" + e.getString("eqid"));
                map.put("magnitude", "Magnitude: " +  e.getString("magnitude"));
                mylist.add(map);            
            }       
        }catch(JSONException e)        {
             Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.main, 
                        new String[] { "name", "magnitude" }, 
                        new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        final ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);  
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);                   
                Toast.makeText(Main.this, "ID '" + o.get("id") + "' was clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

            }
        });
    }
}
```

LogCAT:

```
threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ab0228)
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap
    at com.example.androidhive.CustomizedListView$1.onItemClick(CustomizedListView.java:94)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:292)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1077)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2533)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3198)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

LazyAdapter.java

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data=new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 


   public static HashMap<String, String> song;

    public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); // title
        TextView artist = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.artist); // artist name
        TextView duration = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.duration); // duration
        ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image

         song = new HashMap<String, String>();
        song = data.get(position);

        // Setting all values in listview
        title.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_TITLE));
        artist.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_ARTIST));
        duration.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_DURATION));
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_THUMB_URL), thumb_image);
        return vi;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the logcat with stacktrace of the crash

Comment: Hello Sir posted the error in logcat which is in RED

Comment: Tha nk You David for looking into the question.Please let me know where the code is wrong?

Comment: Post your custom Adapter code..

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what `LazyAdapter` is doing. Looks like it is returning an `Integer` when you call `getItemAtPosition()` instead of the `HashMap` you expect.

Comment: Why position is final..?

Comment: Hello Sir.Thanks for looking into it .The position is final as I eclipse gave a warning to convert it into final when I was trying many things.

Comment: @JamesPatrick And also this   `Toast.makeText(CustomizedListView.this, "ID '" + o + "' was clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` throws exception as `o` is Hashmap you can't print hashmap that way try to use o.get("id") or o.toString()

Comment: @DavidWasser I have added the code for Lazyadapter.java

Comment: @Pragnani Hello Sir I have changed everything as per your say.

Comment: Hello Sir .I have made the changes and executed again :But it is crashing here again

Comment: @JamesPatrick Update your logcat trace..And modified code

Comment: @Pragnani Good comments, however the `Toast.makeText()` will not throw an exception. Using string concatenation (the "+" operator) just calls the `toString()` method on variable `o` and this will always return a `String`, even for `HashMap`.

Comment: @DavidWasser Thank you Sir for everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In you custom Adapter you are returning position instead of Item

```
public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }
```

Try use this

```
 public Object getItem(int position) {
                return data.get(position);
            }
```

This will fix your problem

Comment: Thank YOU SIR you are AWESOME !!. It worked . Am I suppose to do the same for  **public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }**

Comment: @JamesPatrick No it should return position.. keep it as it is

Comment: Basically it was retuning only position(which is int) and not data attached to it but the code you provided resolved that .Am I correct Sir.

Comment: Awesome Sir I will proceed with the code above and display it in new activity If I get stuck I will post the code in new question as I did today and will add comment here to let you know.

Comment: Thank You Sir again for a great answer .Have A GREAT DAY.I will get back to coding.

Comment: @JamesPatrick k..Have a try before posting question..So that you can identify the problem by your self and you can solve that by your self. If you are unable to find even after your effort then post the question..Good day.

Comment: Sure Sir .I always do that .Thank You Sir.